# get excel file header and check if valid excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a very weird situation in which sometimes I will have valid excel and some times like this

[image]

so In case of these randoms I will discard and won't process this . So is there any way to do this ?

and 2nd thing how I can print all headers currently I am getting this

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name.xlsx , sheet_name=key)
print(df.head())
```

but it's not printing headers

Comment: Do you know what to expect in column A1?  If there is a standard header, just look for that.

Comment: Please define "valid", or maybe "invalid", as it applies here. Otherwise we can't translate your logic to code.

Comment: @TimRoberts how to check standard header ? I mean is there any function etc to check ?

Comment: You can work with multi index if that is what you mean. Or do you mean you just want to print a larger head? Which can be done by adding a number in the head function e.g. ```head(10)```.

Comment: There is no "standard header".  If `read_excel` can read it, then clearly is IS an Excel file.